# Write a unicode CString to a file using WriteFile API

Tags: winapi, atl, cstring, writefile

How can I write contents of a CString instance to a file opened by CreateFile using WriteFile Win32 API function?

Please note MFC is not used, and CString is used by including "atlstr.h"

edit: Can just I do

```
WriteFile(handle, cstr, cstr.GetLength(), &dwWritten, NULL);
```

or

```
WriteFile(handle, cstr, cstr.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);
```

?

Comment: Text files have a specification. Which format do you want the resulting file? Who will use the file? You should probably not be writing TCHARs to a file; you should be explicit about the encoding (UTF-16, UTF-8, ANSI, ...).

Comment: I will read the file using notepad. Format? just some lines one after another. I want to be able to open the file in notepad regardless of the encoding of project. Is it impossible or can I?

Comment: What encoding do you want to use? UTF16? UTF8? ANSI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ATL it's like this:

```
CString sValue;
CStringW sValueW(sValue); // NOTE: CT2CW() can be used instead

CAtlFile File;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(File.Create(sPath, GENERIC_WRITE, ...));
static const BYTE g_pnByteOrderMark[] = { 0xFF, 0xFE }; // UTF-16, Little Endian
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(File.Write(g_pnByteOrderMark, sizeof g_pnByteOrderMark));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(File.Write(sValueW, (DWORD) (sValueW.GetLength() * sizeof (WCHAR))));
```

It's byte order mark (BOM) which lets Notepad know that encoding is UTF-16.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pick a text encoding, convert the string to that encoding, and write the text file accordingly. Simplest is ANSI, so basically you would use the `T2CA` macro to convert your `TCHAR` string to ansi, then dump the contents in a file. Something like (untested/compiled):

```
// assumes handle is already opened in an empty new file
void DumpToANSIFile(const CString& str, HANDLE hFile)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    PCSTR ansi = T2CA(str);
    DWORD dwWritten;
    WriteFile(hFile, ansi, strlen(ansi) * sizeof(ansi[0]), &dwWritten, NULL);
}
```

Because it's ANSI encoding though, it will only be readable on computers that have your same code page settings. For a more portable solution, use UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to ANSI can cause problems with code pages, so it is not acceptable in many cases. Here is a function that saves unicode string to unicode text file:

```
void WriteUnicodeStringToFile(const CString& str, LPCWSTR FileName)
{
HANDLE f = CreateFileW(FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (f == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return; //failed
DWORD wr;
unsigned char Header[2]; //unicode text file header
Header[0] = 0xFF;
Header[1] = 0xFE;
WriteFile(f, Header, 2, &wr, NULL);
WriteFile(f, (LPCTSTR)str, str.GetLength() * 2, &wr, NULL); 
CloseHandle(f);
}
```

Using:

```
CString str = L"This is a sample unicode string";
WriteUnicodeStringToFile(str, L"c:\\Sample.txt");
```

Notepad understands unicode text files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need additional casting:

```
WriteFile(handle, (LPCVOID)(LPCTSTR)cstr, cstr.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: 1) If you have to put "I believe" in your answer, it's probably best to not answer. 2) Never cast to void*

Comment: @tenfour: OK, I am sure, not only beleive. Regarding casting to void* - this is WriteFile parameter type. I beleive your post is not constructive...

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you write proper byte order mark in the beginning so that Notepad can read it properly.