# Write CString to file

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, cstring

I am trying to write a cstring to a file, but have so far been unsuccessfull.
I have tried the following:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(Placering, std::ofstream::out);
myfile << output;
myfile.close();
```

This however just seems to print the address of "output" to "myfile".

I then tried

```
for(int i = 0; i < output.getlength(); i++){
    myfile << output[i]
}
```

for every element in output, but that seems to just print the ASCII value of the characters to "myfile".

How do i correctly write my CString to a file?
The content of the CString file can be HTML and rtf code.

EDIT:
I found a solution, by casting the CString to a CStringA

```
std::ofstream myfile;
CStringA output = T2A(stringtoprint);
myfile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out);
for(int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(); i++){
    myfile << output[i];
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: If this is a UNCODE build, [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7500209/2065121) to find out about BOM.

Comment: I'am afraid i don't understand much of what is going on in the answer you linked to. I am very new to C++.

Comment: If you are building a Unicode build (as seems likely), then `CString` represents an array of `wchar_t`, not an array of `char`. In which case you need to write it to `wofstream`, not `ofstream`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found another solution, which i have described in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, by casting the CString to a CStringA

```
myPrintMethod(CString stringtoprint, LPCWSTR myfile){
    std::ofstream myfile;
    CStringA output = T2A(stringtoprint);
    myfile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out);
    for(int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(); i++){
        myfile << output[i];
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: The second parameter name should be fileName. Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different solution

```
myPrintMethod(CString stringtoprint, LPCWSTR myfile){
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out);
myfile << CT2A(stringtoprint);
myfile.close();
```

}